# A solution of the heat equation is more regular where the external force is more regular?

Tags: heat-equation, regularity-theory-of-pdes

I would like to know what is a regularity of heat equation on a subdomain where the external force is more regular, for example, if the external force is zero in a subdoman. Let me clarify my question.

Let $T>0$,  $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\omega\subset\subset \Omega$ be an open set. Let us denote by $Q=\Omega\times (0,T)$ and $\Sigma=\partial \Omega\times (0,T)$.

Consider the problem
$$\begin{cases}
y_t-\Delta y =v1_\omega,\ \text{ in } Q,\\
y\equiv 0,\ \text{ in } \Sigma,\\
y(x,0)=y_0(x), \ x\in \Omega,
\end{cases}$$
where $y_0\in H^2(\Omega)$, $v\in L^2(\omega\times (0,T))$ and $1_\omega$ is the characteristic mapping, that is, it is zero outside of $\omega$ and 1 inside of $\omega$.

We know that this problem has a unique weak solution $y$ such that
$$y\in C^0([0,T];L^2(\Omega))\cap L^2(0,T;H_0^1(\Omega)).$$

My question is: Since $v\equiv 0$ in $\Omega\setminus \omega$, given $\Omega'$ a open set, with smooth boundary, such that $\omega \subset\subset \Omega'$, then what is the regularity of $y$ on $\Omega\setminus \Omega'$? In other words, if we define $u=y\vert_{\Omega\setminus\Omega'}$, then $u$ is a weak solution to the equation
$$u_t-\Delta u=0,\text{ in } (\Omega\setminus\Omega')\times (0,T).$$
Hence, does $u$ have better regularity? Can I conclude that $u\in L^\infty(0,T;\Omega\setminus\Omega')$ and that
$$\operatorname{ess}\,\! \sup_{0\leq t\leq T}\|u(t)\|_{H^2(\Omega\setminus\Omega')}\leq C\|y_0\|_{H^2(\Omega\setminus\Omega')}?$$

Note that, From [Evan's book](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=Xnu0o_EJrCQC&lpg=PP1&dq=evans%20partial%20differential%20equations&hl=pt-BR&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q=evans%20partial%20differential%20equations&f=false)

Theorem 5, if $u$ is a weak solution to the problem
$$\begin{cases}
u_t-Lu =f,\ \text{ in } Q,\\
\color{blue}{ u\equiv 0,\ \text{ in } \Sigma,}\\
u(x,0)=g(x), \ x\in \Omega,
\end{cases},$$
where $L$ is an elliptic operator, $u\in H^2(\Omega)$,  $f\in H^1(0,T;L^2(\Omega))$ then $u\in L^\infty(0,T;\Omega)$ and that
$$\operatorname{ess}\,\! \sup_{0\leq t\leq T}\|u(t)\|_{H^2(\Omega)}\leq C\left(\|f\|_{H^1(0,t;L^2(\Omega)}+\|g\|_{H^2(\Omega)}\right).$$

But here, we have that $u\equiv 0$ in $\Sigma$. When I consider $\Omega\setminus \Omega'$ we have $v\equiv 0$, however we have to consider other boundary condition $\partial \Omega'$. Is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: The estimate $\operatorname{ess}\,\! \sup_{0\leq t\leq T}\|u(t)\|_{H^2(\Omega\setminus\Omega')}\leq C\|y_0\|_{H^2(\Omega\setminus\Omega')}$ doesn't hold. Take $v\equiv0$ and the initial function $y_0\not\equiv0$ s.t. $y_0=0$ on $\Omega\setminus\Omega'$.

Comment: Andrew in your example $v\in C^\infty$ and $y_0\in H^2$, then regularity guarantee that the solution satisfies that inequality. It is a result in the Evan's book. Do you mean $v\neq 0$ and $y_0=0$? And if so, why we don't have this inequality?

Comment: The rhs is equal to zero so the solution $u\not\equiv0$ cannot satisfy the inequality.

Comment: Ok, I get it. But about $\operatorname{ess sup}_{0\leq t\leq T}\|u(t)\|_{H^2(\Omega\setminus \Omega'}\leq C\|y_0\|_{H^2(\Omega)}$?

Comment: Still no. The solution of the homogeneous heat equation $u_t-\Delta u=0$ in $Q= (\Omega\setminus\Omega')\times (0,T)$ depends on its values at $\partial (\Omega\setminus\Omega')\times (0,T)$ (consider $u$ as the solution of the first BVP in $Q$). And those values depend on $v$.